# What is the proper way to go from a String to a *const i8?

Tags: rust, ffi

In my ongoing saga of writing a [safe wrapper](https://github.com/tupshin/cql-ffi/) for the [Cassandra C++ driver](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/), my eye now turns towards avoiding memory leaks when calling C functions with signatures like:

```
cass_string_init2(const char* data, cass_size_t length);
```

or

```
cass_string_init(const char* null_terminated);
```

I have tried a few different approaches that nominally work, and produce a correct result, but I haven't found a way to manage the lifetime of this data properly. Two example approaches are below.

```
pub fn str_to_ref(mystr:&str) -> *const i8 {unsafe{
    let cstr = CString::from_slice(mystr.as_bytes());
    cstr.as_slice().as_ptr()
}}
```

and

```
pub fn str_to_ref(mystr: &str) -> *const i8 {
    let l = mystr.as_bytes();
    unsafe {
        let b = alloc::heap::allocate(mystr.len()+1, 8);
        let s = slice::from_raw_parts_mut(b, mystr.len()+1);
        slice::bytes::copy_memory(s, l);
        s[mystr.len()] = 0;
        return b as *const i8;
    }
}
```

The first does invalid memory accesses like

```
==26355==  Address 0x782d140 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 320 free'd
==26355==    at 0x1361A8: je_valgrind_freelike_block (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi/target/basic)
==26355==    by 0x11272D: heap::imp::deallocate::h7b540039fbffea4dPha (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi/target/basic)
==26355==    by 0x112679: heap::deallocate::h3897fed87b942253tba (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi/target/basic)
==26355==    by 0x112627: vec::dealloc::h7978768019700822177 (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi/target/basic)
==26355==    by 0x112074: vec::Vec$LT$T$GT$.Drop::drop::h239007174869221309 (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi/target/basic)
==26355==    by 0x111F9D: collections..vec..Vec$LT$i8$GT$::glue_drop.5732::h978a83960ecb86a4 (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi/target/basic)
==26355==    by 0x111F6D: std..ffi..c_str..CString::glue_drop.5729::h953a595760f34a9d (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi/target/basic)
==26355==    by 0x112903: cql_ffi::helpers::str_to_ref::hef3994fa55168b90bqd (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi/target/basic)
=
```

while the second doesn't know when to deallocate its memory, resulting in:

```
==29782== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 115
==29782==    at 0x12A5B2: je_mallocx (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi/target/basic)
==29782==    by 0x1142D5: heap::imp::allocate::h3fa8a1c097e9ea53Tfa (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi/target/basic)
==29782==    by 0x114221: heap::allocate::h18d191ce51ab2236gaa (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi/target/basic)
==29782==    by 0x112874: cql_ffi::helpers::str_to_ref::h5b60f207d1e31841bqd (helpers.rs:25)
```

Using either of those two approaches as a starting point, or something completely different, I would really appreciate some guidance on a proper way to accomplish this.

Edit:

Shep's answer *perfectly* solved my issues using cass_string_init and cass_string_init2. Thank you so much. However, I'm still not clear on passing *const i8 params to other functions such as:

```
CASS_EXPORT CassError
cass_cluster_set_contact_points(CassCluster* cluster,
const char* contact_points);
```

which expect to be passed a reference to a null-terminated string.

Based on the previous approach that worked for CassStrings, along with the CString docs, I came up with the following:

```
pub struct ContactPoints(*const c_char);

pub trait AsContactPoints {
    fn as_contact_points(&self) -> ContactPoints;
}

impl AsContactPoints for str {
    fn as_contact_points(&self) -> ContactPoints {
        let cstr = CString::new(self).unwrap();
        let bytes = cstr.as_bytes_with_nul();
        let ptr = bytes.as_ptr();
        ContactPoints(ptr as *const i8)
    }
}
```

(the excessive let bindings there are just to make sure I wasn't missing any subtlety)

and that runs correctly, but valgrind complains:

```
==22043== Invalid read of size 1
==22043==    at 0x4C2E0E2: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22043==    by 0x4F8AED8: cass_cluster_set_contact_points (in /usr/local/lib/libcassandra.so.1.0.0)
==22043==    by 0x11367A: cql_ffi::cluster::CassCluster::set_contact_points::h575496cbf7644b9e6oa (cluster.rs:76)
```

Comment: Shep, once again, you help is greatly appreciated. :) I think I'm almost done with the unsafe parts of the full driver api.

What am I still missing, though? (see edit)

Comment: I've updated my answer. In the future, make sure to use the @-mention in comments, otherwise people won't see that you are talking to them. I just happened to re-read this one. :-)

Comment: You are a god among Rustaceans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Cassandra [C API for cass_string_init2](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/011769c8053f14c1484c13358ce6403c1449bb72/include/cassandra.h#L3141-L3154) looks like:

> Note: This **does not allocate memory**. The object wraps the pointer passed into this function.
>
> ```c
> CASS_EXPORT CassString
> cass_string_init2(const char* data, cass_size_t length);
> ```

That is, it takes a string, *and returns an alternate representation of a string*. That [representation looks like](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/011769c8053f14c1484c13358ce6403c1449bb72/include/cassandra.h#L118-L121):

```c
typedef struct CassString_ {
    const char* data;
    cass_size_t length;
} CassString;
```

This is where you want to use `#[repr(C)]` in the Rust code:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct CassStr {
    data: *const c_char,
    length: size_t,
}
```

The nicest thing you could do is make strings automatically convert to this struct:

```rust
trait AsCassStr {
    fn as_cass_str(&self) -> CassStr;
}

impl AsCassStr for str {
    fn as_cass_str(&self) -> CassStr {
        CassStr {
            data: self.as_bytes(),
            length: self.len(),
        }
    }
}
```

And then have your API accept anything that implements `AsCassStr`. This allows you to have owned variants as well. You may also want to look into `PhantomData` to allow enforcing lifetimes of the `CassStr` object.

**Note** Normally you want to use `CString` to avoid strings with *interior NUL bytes*. However, since the API accepts a length parameter, it's possible that it natively supports them. You'll need to experiment to find out. If not, then you'll need to use `CString` as shown below.

#### Second half of question

Lets take a look at your function, line-by-line:

```rust
impl AsContactPoints for str {
    fn as_contact_points(&self) -> ContactPoints {
        let cstr = CString::new(self).unwrap(); // 1
        let bytes = cstr.as_bytes_with_nul();   // 2
        let ptr = bytes.as_ptr();               // 3
        ContactPoints(ptr as *const i8)         // 4
    }                                           // 5
}
```

1. We create a new `CString`. This allocates a bit of memory somewhere, verifies that the string has no *internal NUL bytes*, then copies our string in, byte-for-byte, and adds a trailing zero.
2. We get a slice that refers to the bytes that we have copied and verified in step 1. Recall that slices are a pointer to data plus a length.
3. We convert the slice to a pointer, ignoring the length.
4. We store the pointer in a structure, using that as our return value
5. The function exits, and **all local variables are freed**. Note that `cstr` is a local variable, and so the bytes it is holding are likewise freed. You now have a *dangling pointer*. Not good!

You need to ensure that the `CString` lives for as long as it needs to. Hopefully the function you are calling doesn't keep a reference to it, but there's no easy way to tell from the function signature. You probably want code that looks like:

```rust
fn my_cass_call(s: &str) {
    let s = CString::new(s).unwrap();
    cass_call(s.as_ptr()) // `s` is still alive here
}
```

The benefit here is that you never store the pointer in a variable of your own. Remember that raw pointers do not have lifetimes, so you have to be very careful with them!